# directive attributes given undefined value sometimes

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-directive

I have created a touch directive on numpad and when i press button sometime i get `null` or `undefined` value in my directive. Here is a code:

```
return {
  restrict: 'E',
  templateUrl: 'partials/template.html',
  require: 'ngModel',
  link: function(scope, elem, attrs, ngModel) {

    elem.bind('touchstart', function(e) {

      var viewValue = ngModel.$viewValue;
      if (e.target.hasAttribute("edit")) {
        var val = viewValue ? viewValue.substring(0, viewValue.length - 1) : '';
        ngModel.$setViewValue(val);
      } else {
        var val = viewValue || '';
        var number = e.target.getAttribute("data-value");
        if (number == null || number.length > 1) {
          var foo = attrs.dataValue;
          $log.info("something wrong with values : " + number + " foo: " + foo);
          return;
        }
        ngModel.$setViewValue(val + number);
      }
      scope.$apply();
    });
  }
};
```

HTML:

```
<kbd data-value="1">
  1
  <div class="background">&nbsp;</div>
</kbd>
<kbd data-value="2">
  2
  <div class="background">ABC</div>
</kbd>
```

Output on console:

```
something wrong with values : null foo: undefined
```

This is happened when i press button frequently on touch screen. Can someone tell me what is wrong?

Comment: don't use e.target, you have elem.

Comment: right, but this is not a problem attrs.dataValue also return undefined

Comment: you could ignore 'data-' parth witg getAttribute. Can you try that? `e.target.getAttribute("value")` instead of `e.target.getAttribute("data-value")`

Comment: How should this will work? in html i am setting attribute like this: <kbd data-value="2">

Comment: AngularJS strips the `data-` prefix. See [AngularJS Developer Guide - Attribute Normalization](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive#normalization).